# Why are morphisms between non-isomorphic indecomposable modules always radical?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

I am trying to follow the construction of the Auslander-Reiten quiver of the Kronecker algebra, given by Barot in his book *Introduction to the Representation Theory of Algebras*.

There, he defines a morphism $f: M \to N$ between $A$-modules $M$, $N$ to be **radical**, if for every morphism $g: N \to M$ it holds true that $\xi = 1_M - g \circ f$ is an isomorphism.

Now, in the proof of lemma 6.2, he states:

> *[...] Since morphisms between non-isomorphic indecomposables are always radical [...]*

I am trying to figure out, why this is the case. I found out that $\ker(\xi)$ cannot be $M$, as this would mean that $g$ is a retraction and hence $N \cong M \oplus \ker(g)$ which yields $M=0$ or $M \cong N$, both of which can not hold by assumption.

However, I think that I mixed up the terms *irreducible module* and *indecomposable module* and hence I am not sure how to proceed from here (if it is even possible).

Comment: I don't think you confused the terms: you stated that if $N$ decomposes as a direct sum then one of those factors is $0$, which is what indecomposable means.

Comment: Captain Lama, this is not the problematic part. However, this only suffices to show that $\ker(\xi) \neq M$. How can I proceed from here to showing that $\xi$ is an isomorphism? For irreducible modules it would follow directly at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Barot is using Example 3.23 of the [same book](https://www.matem.unam.mx/~christof/cursos/12_SAB/1111_RepThBook.pdf),  which is the following:

[image]

By a spectroid he means a $k$-linear category $\mathcal{C}$  such that

1. $\mathcal{C}(x,y)$ is finite dimensional;
2. $\text{End}_{\mathcal{C}}(x,x)$ is local for each $x\in\mathcal{C}$;
3. objects are pairwise non-isomorphic.

For your ends, he  is considering the category whose objects are indecomposable $A$-modules.

Now, the proof of this example is not given, or at least I couldn't find it, in the book. However, the same result is in appendix A3 of [Assem-Simson-Skowronski](https://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/mathematics/algebra/elements-representation-theory-associative-algebras-techniques-representation-theory-volume-1?format=HB&isbn=9780521584234):[image]

and below is the proof of (b):[image]

If you  don't have access to this book, the result (I.1.3) is the following result.

> **Lemma**
>   Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra, then the following are equivalent for $a\in A$:
>
> - $a\in\text{rad}\,A$;
> - $a$ is in the intersection of all left maximal ideals of $A$;
> - for any $b\in A$, the element $1-ab$ has a two sided inverse;
> - for any $b\in A$, the element $1-ab$ has a right inverse;
> - for any $b\in A$, the element $1-ba$ has a two sided inverse;
> - for any $b\in A$, the element $1-ba$ has a left inverse.